# Unable to generate downloadable PDF file from Django website hosted in apache

Tags: javascript, python, django, pdf, request

Im encountering an issue in generating a PDF file from a hosted django website. The website is hosted in apache thorough cpanel python web app. The website is basically a dashboard of all user submissions with a download button at the side. Once you click on the button, a dialog box will pop-up, prompting you to download the pdf file with user submission details. I followed this tutorial to get it to work: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/howto/outputting-pdf/

I added some more code to it using pypdf and reportlab to handle the details from the database and add them to a pdf file to output it. The code works fine on my local computer, but when deployed to my hosting site, it returns a generic error response on my console and an uncommon error-like message saying `io.UnsupportedOperation: fileno` on my webapp stderr.log file.

How my project is set up is that I have a javascript function that makes a GET request to a django function to generate the pdf file on the browser. Here are my code.

javascript:

```js
function downloadPDF(id, date) {
    const csrftoken = getCookie('csrftoken');
    $.ajax({
      url: `/generate-pdf/${id}`,
      method: 'GET',
      headers: {
        'X-CSRFToken': csrftoken,
      },
      mode: 'same-origin',
      xhrFields: {
        responseType: 'blob' // Specify the response type as 'blob'
      },
      
      success: function(response) {
        // Create a temporary URL for the downloaded file
        console.log(response)
        var url = URL.createObjectURL(response);
        // Trigger a download by creating an anchor element and clicking it
        var link = document.createElement('a');
        link.href = url;
        link.download = `${id}-${date}.pdf`;
        link.click();
  
        // Clean up the temporary URL
        URL.revokeObjectURL(url);

      error: function(xhr, status, error) {
        console.error('Error generating PDF:', error);
        // Handle the error or display an error message
      }
    });
  }
```

Django:

```py
def generate_pdf(request, id):
        buffer = io.BytesIO()
        doc = SimpleDocTemplate(buffer, pagesize=letter)
        # Rest of code to generate file
        buffer.seek(0)
        return FileResponse(buffer, as_attachment=True, filename="gen_pdf.pdf")
```

One of the things I have tried to resolve the issue was, removing all my code and testing with a simple GET request for a message from Django to javascript. It works fine on my local computer and the website. So the javascript and Python functions work well.

After trying different things, I'm suspecting that the issue is either from the javascript code  `var url = URL.createObjectURL(response);` or python `FileResponse()` functions. At first, I thought it was the issue with the `io.BytesIO()` due to the error message I got in stderr.log file, but no issue there.

I even typed the main code line to line in the terminal within cpanel and it was all working well up until the `FileResponse`. I couldn't produce the error message I got in the log file and I have no idea where it's coming from. Which is why I suspected it was from the 2 functions I mentioned earlier.

Hope you can help in resolving this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found out what was wrong. I was trying to load a large pdf file into memory which then crashes due to the size. Had to transfer the file in chunks.

Here the updated code that resolved my issue.

```py
from wsgiref.util import FileWrapper

def generate_pdf(request, id):
        buffer = io.BytesIO()
        doc = SimpleDocTemplate(buffer, pagesize=letter)
        # Rest of code to generate file
        wrapper = FileWrapper(buffer)
        response = FileResponse(wrapper, content_type='application/pdf')
        response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=gen.pdf'
        response['Content-Length'] = buffer.tell()
        buffer.seek(0)
        return response
```